# Вопрос из  "Русского медвежонка"

Tags: школьное-задание

На днях с одним из своих пяти внуков я просматривал вопросы прошлых лет конкурса "Русский медвежонок", чтобы подготовить его к состязанию нынешнего года, и наткнулся на вопрос, который никак не поддавался ответу. Вот он: "Художник Тюбик посадил у своего дома малину, сирень, розы и...
А) астры;
Б) бамбук;
В) вишни;
Г) георгины;
Д) клены".
С большим трудом после долгих раздумий мы с женой (она математик) придумали ответ, но он меня не очень убеждает, поэтому не буду сейчас приводить его, чтобы не увести мысль уважаемых коллег в сторону. Возможно, участники форума предложат более убедительный ответ?
Кстати, это вопрос для учеников 2-3 класса

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Поскольку конкурс "Русский медвежонок" - это конкурс по русскому языку, то и ответ мы должны искать с соответствующим обоснованием. Я думаю, правильный ответ вишня. В задании важно каждое слово, для художника важен цвет, поэтому выбираю ответ "вишня":  можно образовать прилагательное "вишневый". (Роза - розовый, сирень - сиреневый, малина - малиновый, вишня - вишневый) Сначала я, правда, начала считать слоги, смотреть на ударение, не получилось - пошла к значению слов.

Comment: ЛарF, я прежде всего обратил внимание на то, что он - художник Тюбик.
Это - "Незнайка из Цветочного города".  

Задание для незнаек...

Comment: Да понятно, что из "Незнайки", но я почему-то всегда ищу какое-то более формальное сходство, а потом уже к значению иду.

Answer (score 4):

Вишню. Все посаженное - кустарники или полукустарники. Это для садовника.
Для художника, конечно, важнее розовый, малиновый, сиреневый и вишневый цвета. ;)
Интересно, какое обоснование даст математик? Цветы на 4 или 5 лепестков?

Comment: Виктор, я честно говоря, тоже изначально подумал, что нужно копать в сторону грам. рода. Т.е. или астра, или вишня. А далее методом исключения. Как известно, за уши притянуть можно любой ответ.

Comment: Интересно, что пути рассуждения разные, результат- один. Это-то и хорошо. Образное ли мышление более развито, или формально-логическое - дети должны прийти к одинаковому  результату.

Comment: Хочу сказать больщое спасибо всем, кто откликнулся на мою просьбу и высказался по поводу этого вопроса. Сегодня внук Илья придет ко мне и прочтет всю переписку по данному вопросу. Возможно, это будет еще один шагок в привлечении его внимания к слову, к его смыслу и грамматическому значению. А еще хочу поделиться радостью: моя большая семья поздравляет старшего внука Максима (4 класс), который вчера написал четвертной диктант на "5", притом что перед этим получил "2" за словарный диктант. Извините, что засоряю блог такими семейными событиями.

Comment: Кстати, все уже обратили внимание, что "плюсики" ставят тут за решение задачи, а что по сути похвалил автора.

Это не в пику ЛарF, и не в личную обиду... Но все же. Чем мой ответ, данный сразу после вопроса хуже? тем что я предложил несколько вариантов решения, о которых не подумал автор? И тем самым показал некорректность задачи?

Answer (score 3):

Да, Виктор, дело здесь в том, что от указанных растений нужно образовать названия цветов. Среди предложенных вариантов получается только с вишней: вишнёвый.

Могу предложить вам курс подготовки к конкурсу "Русский медвежонок", который я сейчас разрабатываю.
Материал представляет собой логически цельный курс подготовки к конкурсу, включающий в себя практику и теорию. Практика включает в себя избранные задачи прошлых лет и абсолютно уникальные задачи, аналогичные тем, которые могут быть на реальном конкурсе. Практическая часть позволяет ознакомиться с примерными формулировками заданий и их направленностью. Теория включает в себя деление задач РМ на типы и подробное изучение каждого типа задач. Это позволяет быть готовым к решению практически любого типа задач, которые могут быть на конкурсе. 
Конечно, теория - это более продуктивный модуль моего курса, нежели практика, так как благодаря идее сведению множества задач к нескольким типам она охватывает максимально широкий круг задач РМ, и для каждого типа предлагаются методы подготовки, а когда это возможно (очень редко!) даже алгоритмы решений. 
Но и практика для подготовки неоценима: благодаря решению избранных (по моему субъективному мнению!) задач, участник не только морально готовится к внешней форме конкурса (30 задач,5 вариантов и т. д.), но и неосознанно начинает понимать, какие задания свойственны Медвежонку. Что ожидать на конкурсе, а чего в нём точно не будет. Итак, если Вы хотите готовиться прямо сейчас, я предлагаю Вам свой курс интенсивной подготовки к "Русскому медвежонку"! 
Если заинтересовало, прошу зайти на мой блог по ссылке http://mirglazamicheloveka.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_8940.html

Comment: Если вас интересует мнение, то вопрос совершенно некорректный.
Как и обоснование. Не стоит учить детей догике сичтать ответ правильным потому, что он нравится взрослым (хотя и это еще бабка надвое сказала).

Comment: Кстати, чтобы меня нельзя было сраху обвинить в тенденциозности.
Вот из предлагаемых на сайте примеров:

(2-3 кл.) Мама купила яблоки, сливы, клубнику и чернику... - весьма неплох 

(6-7 кл.) Какая рыба дала название одному из свойств человеческого характера... - просто неодозначен (Акула - тоже характер)

(10-11 кл.) 5 апреля 1941 года - сомнителен исторически и политически, хотя достоен похвалы за неангажированность.

ЗЫ У Мандельштама нет сихотворения "Веницейская жизнь". Есть неозаглавленное стихотворение, начинающееся со слов "Веницейской жизни, мрачной и бесплодной...".

Comment: Не согласен с Вами.
1. По поводу вишнёвого цвета не понял, почему вопрос некорректен. В объяснении всё логично, на верный ответ должно натолкнуть то, что Тюбик - художник. Если есть логика, которая приводит к правильному ответу и нет другой логики, которая приводит к другому ответу, приведённому среди вариантов, то вопрос, по-моему, корректен.
2. Акула не дала названия никакому свойству человеческого характера, потому что нет слова обозначающего такое свойство: акулистость или акульность, как по Вашему?

Comment: 3. Историческая и политическая достоверность не столь важна в данной ситуации. Главное, в конкурсе по языкознанию то, что вопрос можно взять логически на основании языка (в данном случае, догадавшись об игре слов).
4. Нет и нет. Эти тонкости опять ни к чему. Вопрос решаемый и корректный.
Спасибо.

Comment: 1. Вопрос некорректен потому, что он предполагает испорльзование русского язвка там, где по жизни надо руководствоваться чем-то иным. 
Если я Вас попрошу вычеркнуть лишнее из списка "чашка, ложка, кружка, вилка и пешка", то хоть застрелите меня, лишим будет "пешка", а не вилка. Даже если Вы - профессор-лингвист, кушающий яичницу руками ибо тонкости - опять ни к чему. 

2. Акула - это и есть свойство характера само по себе. Куда ярче "ершистости" характеризует человека. "Акула пера", "акулы капитализма" - ну куда ершу до них?!

Comment: 3. "Историческая и политическая достоверность не столь важна в данной ситуации" - Это снова начсет Тюбика и вишни. Я принимаю абстракцию, когда она удалеят все ненужно по жизни, а у вас наоборот. Если жизнь не лезет под мои идеи - тем хуже для жизни.

Я посмотрел еще задания для 11 класса до белорусских названий включительно - ну там вообще отдельный разговор...

Comment: Евгений, спасибо за ссылку. Успел  пробежаться по блогу и понял, что там у Вас много интересного. Послал ссылку и дочери, чтобы она с сыном позанималась. В ближайшее время погуляю по блогу основательно

Answer (score 0):

Ну а теперь то, что предложила моя жена, математик. Путем "математической логики" она пришла к выводу, что вопрос этот - по русскому языку, поэтому надо рассматривать указанные слова с точки зрения грамматических категорий рода, числа, склонения и т.д. Далее она рассуждала так: "Художник посадил цветы, названия которых являются существительными женского рода и начинаются  с согласных букв. Единственным словом из оставшихся пяти, соответствующим названным требованиям, является слово "вишня". Интересно, кто прав.

Comment: Браво...
Что и требовалось доказать...
задачу "правильно" можно решить десятком методов и никто не будет думать, что хотел сказать дядя автор.

Comment: "Художник посадил цветы, названия которых являются существительными женского рода и начинаются с согласных букв. Единственным словом из оставшихся пяти, соответствующим названным требованиям, является слово "вишня". ==== Слова «цветы», да и слова «вишня» в Задании нет. В Задании важно каждое слово, как сказала Ларf. Так и в Ответе тоже.

Comment: Комментария shampar не понял. )))